# Submit form values before paypal

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to override the paypal submit form below to run some ajax before submitting but for some reason everything up till submitting the actual form is working.

**Paypal Form**

```
<form name="_xclick" id="payWithPaypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@website.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name Here">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.website.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.website.com/ipn.php">
    <input type="submit" id="submitPaypal" class="mailsubmit" value="Pay Now" border="0" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Overriding the submit button**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#submitPaypal').on("click", function(e){
            event.preventDefault();
            tailor();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Ajax that should run then submit the above form**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function tailor(){
             $.ajax({
                url: "info.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {NAME:"test"},
                success: function(data){
                     $('#payWithPaypal').submit();
                }
           });
        }
    </script>
```

Any insight as to why `$('#payWithPaypal').submit();` isn't working would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally figured this one out for some reason which I'm still not really sure why but the submit button needs to be placed out side of the form tags and then it works as it should. If anyone knows why this is the case I'd love to know

Answer (score 4):

Your `event.preventDefault();` bound to the button click doesn't prevent the form submit. This is why your `.ajax()` works only when the submit button is placed outside of the form.

**I'd recommend something like this instead:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#payWithPaypal').submit(function(e) {

    var self = this;

    e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
      url: 'info.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: $(':input', self),
      success: function(json) {
        self.submit();
      }
    });
});

</script>
```